# React - Where is the best place to fetch data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

It is a conceptual question about a better way of fetching data using react and react with redux.

I have a component called `UsersSelect` which is a select component that displays the user information. Currently I'm fetching the user data inside this component to make it more reusable.

I also have an `UsersTable` component which does kind of the same as `UsersSelect` and, sometimes, I have them both rendered on the same screen which causes two identical fetches. To avoid this, I'm using *redux-saga* with *takeLatest*.

So my questions are:

- Is it ok to use this?
- Should I put the fetch logic on the parent component? Like an `UsersPage` component?
- Is there another better option to simplify this?

Comment: IMHO, you have parent and child components to make reusable non-repeated code. In general, I fetch data in the parent and have states to decide when to fetch the data or not.

Comment: But if I use this component in other pages like EmployeesPage and FavoritesPage I'll replicate the fetch and display logic as well, right?

Comment: I would not say it is imperative not to replicate code. But, if you have common things like API calls, maybe you want another module that does those calls. Then, import that one in each page. Alternatively, those pages can have a parent which calls the API and propagates it to its children via props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Miro J.'s comment.

Since you're using the same data into two different components, it'd be better to fetch the data in the parent and pass it down as props to the children.

In your case, (it seems) both your components are very closely related.

In cases in which the components are not so close, but you'd still need the data, you could also load the data when setting up the root App component.

Comment: But loading the data on the root App component doesn't look a good option since the user can access or not the UsersPage so the App can loads unusage data right?

Comment: Then, have states that would load or not the data based on where the user is/was.

Comment: Correct @BrunoQuaresma, in this case you'd be over fetching data. You have to _estimate_ if visiting the user page is a common case. If it is, since the fetch occurs  asynchronously, it might be a good idea, because the data will be ready in the moment the user visits that page.

Answer (score 0):

For react architecture, without redux , fetch data is working in parent, and yes UsersPage component should has data for the child components for work, but with redux you has some options, like to create a [presentational components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components) , or implement a [factory pattern](https://codepen.io/cahnory/pen/wgEypw) but this requiere that backend architecture couple

```
const factoryComponent = (FactoryComponent, DefaultComponent, props) => ({
      Component: FactoryComponent || props.component || DefaultComponent,
      props: { ...props, component: FactoryComponent ? props.component : fetch(url).then(data=>console.log(data)); },
    })
```